# Blessing over a wine-water mix

Tags: halacha, blessing, grapes-wine, water

Someone I know likes to mix (commercial) grape juice or wine with water or seltzer and drink the result. Of course, the first of those two ingredients normally requires "*hagafen*" and "*al hagefen*", while the second requires "*shehakol*" and "*bore n'fashos*". What proportions (and perhaps quantities) of each ingredient would require the recitation over the mixture of each of the aforementioned benedictions?

For what it's worth, note that United States commercial grape juices often include uncut grape-juice concentrate in addition to the juice.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you need 1/6 (17%) of wine or grape juice to still be able to say *hagefen*. The issue is that wine nowadays is already diluted. The proper way therefore appears to be to first say the blessing *hagefen* on the undiluted grape juice or wine then drink the mix (water drunk after *hagefen* doesn't require a separate blessing).

Sources:

Aish [writes](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/7-Fruit-Juice--Wine.html)

> Wine that is watered down retains the bracha
>
> When diluted, grape juice easily loses its distinctive taste.
> Therefore, when diluting grape juice with any significant amount of
> water you can no longer say [*hagefen*].
>
> In practice, since it can be difficult to determine whether or not the
> taste of wine or grape juice has been significantly diminished when
> diluted, it is recommended that you say Ha'gafen on non-diluted wine
> or grape juice before drinking the diluted beverage.

[PracticalHalacha](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/halacha/1593-borei_pri_hagafen___mixed_drinks__wine_grape_juice) writes

> Say borei pri ha'gafen on drinks of wine or grape juice mixed with
> water if at least 1/7th of the total volume is wine (or grape juice)
> but the mixture but also still be considered to be wine or grape
> juice.

Not everyone agrees with the above, see e.g., [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2014/09/15/adding-water-to-grape-juice/)

> Some authorities are stringent with regard to grape juice (unlike
> wine), and maintain that if grape juice is diluted with water it loses
> the Borei Peri HaGafen blessing. Although other authorities are
> lenient concerning adding a small amount, this will only be true
> insofar as the grape juice retains its principle taste and strength
> [...] See Shut Minchas Shlomo no. 4, who is particularly stringent
> concerning adding water to grape juice; a similar ruling has been
> given by Rav Elyashiv z”l.

See more sources and details from Shulchan Aruch Harav [here](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/wine-mixed-with-water/) and [KSA 49:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.49.3?lang=bi).

Note this is only for Ashkenazim, Sefaradim *pasken* differently (I believe using 50% instead of 1/6).

Comment: "wine nowadays is already diluted" That's rather unexpected. All wineries dilute their wine before sale? What did it start as? I don't see that mentioned on the labels. 'Wine from concentrate'?

Comment: All I don't know but some/many is for sure. There is a famous issue with R Ovadia Yossef not agreeing to some wines "for they are heavily diluted with water" (see [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=3057)). I asked a friend of mine who has a (kosher) winery and will bring back his answer. See also the last source in my answer, from Aruch Hashulchan

Comment: You mention 1/6 but I don't see that in any of the quotations you include.

Comment: @msh210 second quote above in yellow, first line - fourth reference above (last line, SAHarav), second line - see also background section there in the bottom

Comment: Friend who runs a winery came back saying they don't dilute as they do high-end wine. It does happen in other places

Comment: "second quote above in yellow, first line" says 1/7.

Comment: @msh210 Yes I saw this - I believe one is speaking before mixing (1 part wine, 6 parts water) and one after mixing (1 out of 1+6) - so went with the more conservative of both - but maybe these are two different opinions

Comment: For anybody else who was curious,, the dilution done by wineries is apparently [before fermentation](https://www.winebusiness.com/tools/?go=winemaking.calc&cid=5).  They're not making wine-concentrate and then diluting it when they bottle; the issue is that grapes with too much sugar can impede fermentation.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I'm definitely curious.  When looking at wines on the store shelves, it seems that within the wine types (pinot noir, chardonnay, burgundy, muscatel, etc), they all seem to be within a percent or two, like there's a standard range for each type.  In order to get results like that(xxx's Chardonnay is always 12 percent, for example) the dilution to the final alcohol content has to be done after fermentation, no?

Comment: @Gary wine-making is more science than art; given knowledge of the sugar and yeast going in, you can reliably predict the alcohol level coming out.  Within some parameters (that are a better fit for [Beer, Wine, and Spirits](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com) than here), you can tune the output by adjusting the inputs.  Before this question I'd assumed that dilution was (a) post-fermentation and (b) only something you saw in cheap wines, but today I learned otherwise. (Also [asked this there](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/7148/43).)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Thanks for the clues!  I just figured it was similar to distilled spirits, where it comes out of the still and then gets diluted to the standard 40 percent or whatever, except for the expensive "small batch" products, which can end up bottled @ over 50 percent. Ah, the wonders of Science!

Comment: I heard yesterday from R. Eliyahu Elharar, the chief rabbi of Modiin, whose duties include heading the city's kashruth agency, that wineries he's familiar with in Israel nowadays dilute so the wine is at least 75% of the diluted mixture and often more like 90%. If I understood his Hebrew correctly, which is always a point of doubt.

Comment: I can't quote him, but I heard from a choshuv Rav years ago that people generally say it upside down: Wine in the old days used to be "much stronger", so 1/6 is okay. Our wine is weak or diluted, so you can't add more water, or much more. But he held that the difference was actually that they used to drink it like water. See the gemara on Birkas Aveilim (Kesubot?), where they drank like a dozen cups. That would have me under the table sick. They added a lot of water in the old days.