# What bracha for a mixture of apple and grape juice?

Tags: blessing

If one is drinking a mixture of apple and grape juice, what bracha does one recite -- *shehakol* or *hagafen*?  If it matters, I am interested in all three of the following situations:

- Mostly apple juice with some grape
- Mostly grape juice with some apple
- A 50/50 split

Comment: related - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88614/blessing-over-a-wine-water-mix

Comment: Machloket poskim see rema an pri megadim