# Grape juice vs. Diluted Wine

Tags: grapes-wine, kiddush, four-cups-wine

[Here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/may-grape-juice-be-used-for-the-four-cups-during-the-seder/#_ftn21) it mentions that it is better to mix wine and grape juice than to have plain grape juice. How about mixing water with wine; is the diluted wine still more preferable for kiddush and havdalah? (And does it matter the ratio of wine to water?)

In addition, a Rosh Kolel has mentioned that it is questionable if one fulfills his obligation of חרות with grape juice for the four cups. Has anyone seen a source for this? And would this impact the advantage (if there is one) grape juice has over diluted wine on Pesach?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88614/blessing-over-a-wine-water-mix.